# Summarizing a specific column with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

For my assignment I need to create an object which contains, for each
combination of `Sex` and `Season`, the number of different sports in the `olympics` data set. The columns of this object should be called `Competitor_Sex`, `Olympic_Season`, and `Num_Sports`,
respectively.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
object <- olympics %>%
  group_by(Sex, Season) %>%
  summarise(Num_Sports = ???)
```

I'm having trouble with defining the third column, which is the number of sports. My data looks like this:

```
structure(list(Name = c("A Lamusi", "Juhamatti Tapio Aaltonen", 
"Andreea Aanei", "Jamale (Djamel-) Aarrass (Ahrass-)", "Nstor Abad Sanjun"
), Sex = c("M", "M", "F", "M", "M"), Age = c(23L, 28L, 22L, 30L, 
23L), Height = c(170L, 184L, 170L, 187L, 167L), Weight = c(60, 
85, 125, 76, 64), Team = c("China", "Finland", "Romania", "France", 
"Spain"), NOC = c("CHN", "FIN", "ROU", "FRA", "ESP"), Games = c("2012 Summer", 
"2014 Winter", "2016 Summer", "2012 Summer", "2016 Summer"), 
    Year = c(2012L, 2014L, 2016L, 2012L, 2016L), Season = c("Summer", 
    "Winter", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer"), City = c("London", 
    "Sochi", "Rio de Janeiro", "London", "Rio de Janeiro"), Sport = c("Judo", 
    "Ice Hockey", "Weightlifting", "Athletics", "Gymnastics"), 
    Event = c("Judo Men's Extra-Lightweight", "Ice Hockey Men's Ice Hockey", 
    "Weightlifting Women's Super-Heavyweight", "Athletics Men's 1,500 metres", 
    "Gymnastics Men's Individual All-Around"), Medal = c(NA, 
    "Bronze", NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5"), class = "data.frame")
```

This is probably solved in an easy way. Could someone help me? Would be appreciated a lot!

Best Regards,

Comment: can u show the expected output

Comment: Is it not simply: `df %>%
  group_by(Sex, Season) %>%
  summarise(Num_Sports = n()) %>%
  setNames(c("Competitor_Sex", "Olympic_Season", "Num_Sports"))`

Comment: I'd figure that the expected output of the Num_Sports column is a column that shows the number of sports for that combination of Sex and Season. The use of ``` Num_Sports = n()``` gives the amount of rows( = the total amount of participants), which adds up to 36.000.

Answer (score 1):

Grouping twice should work:

```
olympics %>% 
  group_by(Sex, Season, Sport) %>% 
  summarise(n()) %>% 
  group_by(Sex, Season) %>%
  summarise(n())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the equivalent of `length(unique(` from dplyr: `n_distinct`:

```
olympics %>% 
  group_by(Sex, Season) %>% 
  summarise(Sports = n_distinct(Sport)) %>%
  rename(Competitor_Sex = Sex, Olympic_Season = Season) # To rename the columns
```